# Is there a way to get/set the factorization of large sparse matrices within Eigen solvers?

Tags: c++, serialization, sparse-matrix, eigen, suitesparse

I have a program where the system matrix within the sparse solver (using the Eigen library) is often the same, and could be precomputed once and loaded as a file. Ideally I would want to serialize the whole solver, but there seems to be no way to do that with Eigen.

I am currently using `CholmodSupernodalLLT`, so I suppose one way could be to subclass `CholmodSupernodalLLT` and find a way to serialize `cholmod_factor`, however I am at a loss on how to serialize this type as well.

I am willing to use other solvers (preferably LLT) or even other libraries if they have this capability.

Comment: If you are using `CholmodSupernodalLLT` then look at Cholmod's userguide to see if Cholmod offers that. If so, then you can indeed subclass `CholmodSupernodalLLT` to easily achieve your goals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ggael, however it does not. Do any of the other Eigen solvers allow for serialization?

Comment: I ended up writing my own function building on `cholmod_copy_factor` to serialize to a file stream.